# (Bash) rename files but give it a new extension that will count up.. (md5sum)

Tags: bash, rename, md5sum

I need to rename all files in a folder and give it a new file extension. I know how I can rename files with bash. The problem I have is, I need to rename it to:

`file.01` `file.02` `file.03` and counting up for all files found.

Can somebody provide me an example where to start?

This is what i need:

```
md5sum * | sed 's/^\(\w*\)\s*\(.*\)/\2 \1/' | while read LINE; do
   mv $LINE
done
```

but that doesnt give it an extension that will go from `file.01` `file.02` `file.03` etc.

Comment: This isn't very clear. Do you want the counter to be per-md5sum, or global? Give an example of the desired output names. (Also, `\w` isn't valid in standard grep, which doesn't support PCRE).

Answer (score 2):

If one reads your requirements literally...

```
counter=0
for file in *; do
  read sum _ <<<"$(md5sum "$file")"
  printf -v file_new "%s.%02d" "$sum" "$counter"
  mv -- "$file" "$file_new"
  (( counter++ ))
done
```

This is less efficient than reading the filenames from md5sum's output, but more reliable, as globbing handles files with unusual names (newlines, special characters, etc) safely.

Comment: Hi Charles, Thank you for your answer. What i want is that it creates a md5sum with an extension that counts up for every file found.          


ddshfbdfuydfgudgfuygdsfug.01
sdujfhiuh3whechbuecbywecc.02
djsfisufniudshfiusdhfiuhh.03 etc...

i think your example will work!

Answer (score 0):

something line this:

```
i=0
for f in *
do
   if [ -f $f ]; then 
     i=`expr $i + 1` 
     if [ $i -lt 10 ]; then 
       i=0$i
     fi
     sum=`md5sum $f | cut -d ' ' -f 1` 
     mv $f $sum.$i 
   fi
done
```

Comment: This is broken for several reasons. For instance, `[ -f $f ]` won't work correctly on filenames containing spaces, wildcard characters, etc. Also, numbers starting with zeros are interpreted as octal, not decimal, in shell arithmetic.

Comment: that's why title says: something line this